# Barchart with dummies

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset with the following explicit dummy variables: "Kidhome" and "Teenhome". Of course, for each row where both "Kidhome" and "Teenhome" = 0 that implies an implicit variable that is neither "Teen nor kids at home".

I also have another variable (categorical) that is "marital status"

INPUT:
df['Marital_Status'].value_counts()

OUTPUT:
Married     2108
Together    1257
Single      1052
Divorced     437
Widow        146
Name: Marital_Status, dtype: int64.

Now I wonder if there is a way:

1. To create a barchart in seaborn to count all three dummies (including the implicit one by giving it a name in the plot) and,
2. At the same time, the hue is the categorical variable "MaritalStatus" to each one of the 3 bins with dummies ploted?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the implicit column `Neitherhome`:

```
df['Neitherhome'] = (df.Kidhome.eq(0) & df.Teenhome.eq(0)).astype(int)
```

2. Aggregate the grouped sums:

```
data = df.groupby('Marital_Status').sum().reset_index()
```

3. Plot with `hue='Marital_Status'`:

```
sns.catplot(data=data.melt('Marital_Status'),
            kind='bar',
            x='variable',
            y='value',
            hue='Marital_Status')
```

[image: Figure output]